# Pandas count number of astype errors

Tags: pandas, types

Given a Series of type `object` I would like to know how many elements could successfully be cast to a given type, using the [`.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) function.

For example trying to cast the following series to an `float32`:

```py
s = pd.Series([1.1, 'foo', 3, '4.3', np.nan, 6, 'bar'])
```

The expected output of the function would just be the count of errors, in this case:

```
2
```

(note: `np.nan` does successfully cast to `float32`)

What would be the easiest way to achieve this with pandas?

Comment: @anky that doesn't quite work for my use case (I updated my question to to be more clear).  But also, that wouldn't work getting the errors trying to cast non-numeric types.

Comment: The expected out put would just be the count, in this case `2`.

Comment: That does work in this case, but it's a bit convoluted & still doesn't account for non-numeric types.  I'd like to be able to use this function for counting errors when casting to `datetimes` or anything else.

Comment: You cant, each and every data type has its own method, you can replace `pd.to_numeric` to `pd.to_datetime` for dates though following the answer I posted

Comment: Thinking out loud, is there a way to test if a specific value can be cast to a `dtype`?  Then do something like: `s.apply( lambda: <check type> ).sum()`?

Comment: If you are okay with `apply`, maybe you can run a for loop over the series with a `try/except`...

Comment: This is a dumb question, but how would I write that casting operation?  I'd like it to line up with the pandas `astype` casts.  Is `try/catch` around `float(x)` going to have the same results as `s.astype('float32')`?

Comment: You don't need to resort to Python built-ins, you can `getattr` on `np` for the types, including datetime e.g. `type_ = getattr(np, type_str)`. Then `try` casting as `type_(val)` and catch where it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, you could try `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` and then filter the nan values out

```
int(pd.to_numeric(s,errors='coerce').isna().mask(s.isna()).sum())
#2
```

---

With `try` and `except`:

```
def fun(ser):
    l=[]
    for i in ser:
        try:
            np.float32(i)
        except ValueError:
            l.append(i)
    return l

s.isin(fun(s)).sum()
#2
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you.